angular 8 packages conflict during install
Problem with build .NET Core + Angular project
there is unknown for me project. I need do some small fix.
I've tried to build them:

dotnet publish -c Release -r win-x64 --self-contained false --output
"D:\PathToOutputDirectory\project"

got error:
  npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
  npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
  npm ERR!
  npm ERR! While resolving: angular-recaptcha3@2.0.0
  npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@8.0.0
  npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
  npm ERR!   @angular/common@"8.0.0" from the root project
  npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^8.0.0 || ^9.0.0-0" from @angular/cdk@8.2.3
  npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/cdk
  npm ERR!     @angular/cdk@"^8.2.3" from the root project
  npm ERR!   8 more (@angular/forms, @angular/platform-browser, ...)
  npm ERR!
  npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
  npm ERR! peer @angular/common@">=10.0.0 <12.0.0" from angular-recaptcha3@2.0.0
  npm ERR! node_modules/angular-recaptcha3
  npm ERR!   angular-recaptcha3@"^2.0.0" from the root project
  npm ERR!
  npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/common@11.2.14
  npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
  npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@">=10.0.0 <12.0.0" from angular-recaptcha3@2.0.0
  npm ERR!   node_modules/angular-recaptcha3
  npm ERR!     angular-recaptcha3@"^2.0.0" from the root project
  npm ERR!
  npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
  npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
  npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

in 'package.json' I see:
{
  "name": "project1",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:ssr": "ng run project1:server:dev",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "8.0.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^3.7.0",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "8.0.0-rc.1",
    "@types/html2canvas": "^1.0.0",
    "angular-recaptcha3": "^2.0.0",
    "angular-tree-component": "^8.5.6",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^9.0.0",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "browserslist": "^4.8.2",
    "caniuse-lite": "^1.0.30001016",
    "ckeditor4-angular": "^2.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.6.11",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "date-fns": "^2.16.1",
    "jquery": "3.4.1",
    "jspdf": "^1.4.1",
    "leaflet-image": "^0.4.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng-pick-datetime": "^7.0.0",
    "oidc-client": "^1.10.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "subsink": "^1.0.2",
    "text-mask-addons": "^3.8.0",
    "uuid": "^3.3.3",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.800.6",
    "@angular/cli": "8.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "8.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "~11.10.5",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.3.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "typescript": "3.4.5"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.9.3",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1"
  }
}

application needs angular/common version 8.
angular-recaptcha3 needs in deps angular/common version 10+.
I've tried different versions of angular-recaptcha3 - nothing helped.
I've tried to set in application angular/common version 10 - even more package conflicts in result.
previous developer said me that he can build without errors.
I don't understand how is it possible.
how can I unify all package versions in this case?
can you help me, I'm new in NPM dependencies.

I found the root cause of conflicts and running npm with options like '--legacy-peer-deps'. simply Angular 8 needs Node 12 version instead of my previously installed 18 version.
after that build passed OK.
